# How to check the log4j version in wildfly 10 and upgrade it?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly-10

When i go to directory

`{WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/log4j/main`

i see only `module.xml` file inside it, no any `log4j jar` is there.

So i have two questions:

1. How can i check exactly which version of log4j is packed with my wildfly 10 ?
2. Is it possible to upgrade the `log4j` version of wildfly module ?

Comment: There is no `log4j` in WildFly, only `jboss.logging`, which also contains some classes from `log4j` and other `java.logging` implementations...

Comment: You could add `log4j` to your application, thus not using the WildFly module...

Comment: WildFly uses https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j-jboss-logmanager for it's log4j implementation. It's a fork essentially that delegates to jboss-logmanager for tighter integration. The current version is 1.2.16.